# Hadoop Global Property Conf.Set / Conf.Get in Cleanup()?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to use Global Variables in Hadoop via the Conf.set() and Context.getConfiguration().get() methods.

However, these don't seem to be working inside a Cleanup method I'm using - Though I am able to use the properties in Mapper and Reducer. Is is strange or normal behaviour?

Is there any other way of propagating the value of a variable across MapReduce Jobs, and inside cleanup method of a hadoop job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters set on the Job class are coming properly in the cleanup method.

The following is in the main method

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("test", "123");
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

The following is the Mapper#cleanup method

```
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
    InterruptedException {

    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    String param = conf.get("test");
    System.out.println("clean p--> param = " + param);

}
```

The O/P of the above is

> clean p--> param = 123

Check the code again. BTW, I tested it against 0.21 release.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, it's working now. I was doing a stupid mistake.

Comment: Make sure that conf.set("test", "123") is before Job object creation.